# Functional Derivatives of functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm confused over the procedure of finding derivatives for functions. I mainly built my understanding from the following sources, which doesn't seem to fit each other very well:

1. I found the definition for functional derivative [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).
2. In [this paper](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2004/KivSmoWil04.pdf), it states that from the reproducing property of the kernels, $f(x)=\langle f,K(x,\cdot)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$, and therefore $\partial_f f(x)=K(x,\cdot)$.

Additionally, the paper states that if we wish to compute $\partial_{f}\ell(f(x))$, the chain rule sets in and gives us $\partial_{f}\ell(f(x))=\ell'(f(x))K(x,\cdot)$.

3. In [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/dai16.pdf), mainly last line of page 986 to the first few lines of page 987, the way of finding functional derivative seems to be different than the other two as well.

Can someone help me explain how the derivatives of 2 and 3 are calculated? Are they extensions of the definition given in 1? Furthermore, if $f(x)$ belongs to $L_2$ or $L_1$, what is $\partial_f f(x)$ for a fixed $x$?

Comment: 1) and 2) use the same notion of functional derivatives, while 3) uses a stochastic functional gradient. I am not familiar with stochastic calculus, but regarding 1) and 2), it can be explained roughly as follows. If $L(f)$ is a functional of $f$, let $k$ be a smooth function with compact support, say, and expand $L(f+k) = L(f) + L'(f)k + O(k^2)$. Here $L'(f)$ is the directional derivative of $L$ in the direction of $k$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! By $L'(f)k$, do you mean the inner product of the Hilbert space when applied to (2)?

Comment: If $L(f) = <f, K(x,.)>$, then $L(f+\kappa) = <f+\kappa, K(x,.)> = L(f) + <\kappa, K(x,.)>$, and we see that the directional derivative $L'(f)$ in the direction of $\kappa$ is $<-, K(x,.)>$, which people simply abbreviate as $K(x,.)$. In particular, if $\kappa = f$, then the directional derivative of $L$ in the direction of $f$ is also $K(x,.)$. It takes a while to get used to these things. Look up the Euler-Lagrange equations as a warm-up exercise!

Comment: Strictly speaking, $L'(f)k$ should be written as $L'(f)(k)$, and you can think of it as a linear functional $L'(f)$ applied to $k$.

Comment: I see. That's helpful!

Comment: Here's another explanation that I've convinced myself with. It uses (1) in "Boosting Algorithms as Gradient Descent", Basically, the functional derivative is another function, and when evaluated at $y$, you perturb the original function slightly at that point. For the RKHS, suppose we want to evaluate $\partial_f f(x)$ at $y$. The evaluating function in RKHS is $K(y,\cdot)$. Therefore, the perturbation can be done using $\langle f+\alpha K(y,\cdot),K(x,\cdot)\rangle$. Taking derivative with respect to $\alpha$ gives $\partial_f f(x)=K(x,\cdot)$. Is this interpretation reasonable?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it is a 100% correct. Think of $L'(f)$ as the functional gradient of $L$ at $f$. Then $L'(f)$ is a linear functional which associates to each perturbation $k$ a number. Often one can write a linear functional as the $L^2$ inner product with a fixed function, say $L'(f)(k) = \int_x J(x) k(x) dx$. In this case, one often writes, by abuse of notation, that $L'(f) = J$, but they really mean the previous functional. For instance, in a Hilbert space one often identifies the Hilbert space with its dual using the inner product (see the Riesz representation theorem).

Comment: Think that you are doing calculus, in the usual way, but on an infinite-dimensional space consisting of functions satisfying a condition (a functional space). Maybe this helps too.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think it's better to go with the definition of Frechet derivative in Banach spaces. The derivative is a linear operator. I was thinking of putting it in the mirror descent and I got confused of what it means to have exponential of a linear operator.